# Retrieve start and end point of an arc using NetDxf for c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, cad, dxf

I need to retrieve the start and end point of an Arc entity using NetDxf to analyze my .Dxf file. So far i was only able to retrieve the center and the angle of the arc. Is there a way to retrieve the start and the end point using NetDxf library for c#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a DXF file, an arc is defined by the following properties:

- Center (DXF 10)
- Radius (DXF 40)
- Start Angle (DXF 50)
- End Angle (DXF 51)

Where the start/end angles are always measured counter-clockwise from the x-axis of the object-coordinate-system (OCS) plane in which the arc resides.

From these properties, you can easily obtain the start & end points by calculating points at an angle equal to either the start or end angle from the center point, at a distance equal to the radius, i.e.:

```
Start Point = Center + (Radius*cos(StartAngle), Radius*sin(StartAngle))
```

Comment: This seems to only work when the Normal vector is {0,0,1}. I am trying to parse a file where there are Arcs where N={0,0,-1}. In this case the start and end points calculated using this formula appear not to be correct. Is there a version of this that takes into account the Normal vector?

Comment: Is your Center expressed relative to OCS?